# Getting "Property 'getDisplayMedia' does not exist on type 'MediaDevices'" in Angular

Tags: angular

In my Angular app, there is a requirement to record screen. I've used `navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia` to capture screen. It is working in local. But could see errors in the command line like `Property 'getDisplayMedia' does not exist on type 'MediaDevices'.`. Because of this error, I could not generate the build file.

Here is my code:

```
 const videoOptions = {
   video: {
    cursor: 'always'
   },
   audio: true,
 };

this.captureStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia(videoOptions);
```

I'm using

- Angular CLI: 11.0.2
- TS: 4.0.5

Thank you

Comment: did you verify the Browser compatibility? witch browser you do use? you can find some good lib that manage the different browser

Comment: @nicearma, I'm using Chrome. It is working as expected when I run in local. But getting the above mentioned error message in the command line.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Like you can see the getDisplayMedia is not define in the typescript definitions

```
/** Provides access to connected media input devices like cameras and microphones, as well as screen sharing. In essence, it lets you obtain access to any hardware source of media data. */
interface MediaDevices extends EventTarget {
    ondevicechange: ((this: MediaDevices, ev: Event) => any) | null;
    enumerateDevices(): Promise<MediaDeviceInfo[]>;
    getSupportedConstraints(): MediaTrackSupportedConstraints;
    getUserMedia(constraints?: MediaStreamConstraints): Promise<MediaStream>;
    addEventListener<K extends keyof MediaDevicesEventMap>(type: K, listener: (this: MediaDevices, ev: MediaDevicesEventMap[K]) => any, options?: boolean | AddEventListenerOptions): void;
    addEventListener(type: string, listener: EventListenerOrEventListenerObject, options?: boolean | AddEventListenerOptions): void;
    removeEventListener<K extends keyof MediaDevicesEventMap>(type: K, listener: (this: MediaDevices, ev: MediaDevicesEventMap[K]) => any, options?: boolean | EventListenerOptions): void;
    removeEventListener(type: string, listener: EventListenerOrEventListenerObject, options?: boolean | EventListenerOptions): void;
}
```

so you can use:

```
// @ts-ignore
await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia...
```

You can find the problem here https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33232

Answer (score 2):

Now it's fixed at typescript 4.4. So you can just update it "npm i -D typescript@4.4" or "npm i -D typescript@latest"

Answer (score 0):

On a work around you can cast navigator as any and use it

```
var browser = <any>navigator;
```